# Octave keyboard input function to filter concatenated string and integer?

Tags: input, filter, keyboard, concatenation, octave

if we write `12wkd3`, how to choose/filter `123` as integer in octave?

example in octave:

```
A = input("A?\n")  
A?  
12wkd3   
A = 123
```

while `12wkd3` is user keyboard input and `A = 123` is the expected answer.

Comment: Try using code formatting, it's fun!

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the general form you're looking for is taking an arbitrary string from the user input, removing anything non-numeric, and storing the result it as an integer:

```
A = input("A? /n",'s');
A = int32(str2num(A(isdigit(A))));
```

example output:

```
A?
324bhtk.p89u34
A = 3248934
```

to clarify what's written above:

- in the input statement, the `'s'` argument causes the answer to get stored as a string, otherwise it's evaluated by Octave first. most inputs would produce errors, others may be interpreted as functions or variables.
- `isdigit(A)` produces a logical array of values for `A` with a 1 for any character that is a 0-9 number, and 0 otherwise.

  `isdigit('a1 3 b.') = [0 1 0 1 0 0 0]`
- A(isdigit(A)) will produce a substring from A using only those values corresponding to a 1 in the logical array above.

  `A(isdigit(A)) = 13`
- that still returns a string, so you need to convert it into a number using `str2num()`.  that, however, outputs a double precision number. so finally to get it to be an integer you can use `int32()`